Google Firestore Database unable to connect in IIS (Laragon Apache is fine) "Empty address list:" Error :14
I am running (Windows) IIS with PHP 8.1, grpc + sodium. I have the credentials file from Google Firebase, and I'm just reading from a collection called "info".
On the same machine I am running IIS and Apache, the same code works fine in Apache (Laragon) but not IIS. IIS returns this error:

{
"error": "{\n    "message": "empty address list: ",\n    "code": 14,\n    "status": "UNAVAILABLE",\n    "details": []\n}"
}

I have tried PHP8.1, 8.2 & 8.3 with the same error.
I have created a test function to help, this is the function I am running.
public function testFirestore()
    {
        $credentialsPath = base_path(env('FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS'));
        putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . $credentialsPath);
        putenv('GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG');
        putenv('GRPC_TRACE=all');

        try {
            // Log the credentials path and environment variable
            Log::info('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: ' . getenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'));
            Log::info('Service account file exists: ' . (file_exists($credentialsPath) ? 'yes' : 'no'));

            Log::info('GRPC_VERBOSITY: ' . getenv('GRPC_VERBOSITY'));
            Log::info('GRPC_TRACE: ' . getenv('GRPC_TRACE'));

            $firestore = new FirestoreClient([
                'projectId' => '[projectid]',
            ]);

            $collection = $firestore->collection('info');
            $documents = $collection->documents();

            $result = [];
            foreach ($documents as $document) {
                $result[] = [
                    'id' => $document->id(),
                    'data' => $document->data()
                ];
            }

            return response()->json($result);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error('Firestore error: ' . $e->getMessage());
            return response()->json(['error' => $e->getMessage()], 500);
        }
    }

Happy to send my php.ini if that helps....

I'm not a PHP dev. A clarifying question|statement: Firebase (!) credentials aren't Google Application Default Credentials. Firebase isn't Firestore. This doesn't explain the error as I would expect an unauthenticated error but, if your Firebase credentials include Firebase API Keys and Auth Domain etc., then these can't be used to authenticate to Firestore Client. FirestoreClient shouldn't need any parameters as this can be inferred from the credentials.

The error you're encountering indicates that the gRPC client in PHP is unable to resolve or connect to the server address, this issue can occur due to a few different reasons, I suggest you enable detailed logging for gRPC and PHP under IIS to get more information.

I've enabled the logging (there is alot of data there..))
chand=000002A326287A70 lb_call=000002A326076000: adding pending batch at index 0
chand=000002A326287A70 lb_call=000002A326076000: grabbing LB mutex to get picker
I1725544810.338000000 chand=000002A326287A70 lb_call=000002A326076000: performing pick with picker=000002A326197CF0
I1725544810.339000000 chand=000002A326287A70 lb_call=000002A326076000: LB pick failed: UNAVAILABLE: empty address list:
I'm not sure where to look next... any help would be appreciated.

Turns out the pem certificate was not correct..
Download the cert from here...
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/etc/roots.pem
Add a env var with a key of "GRPC_DEFAULT_SSL_ROOTS_FILE_PATH" and the value of the path you stored the download. "C:\dev\certs\roots.pem". Then reboot.
